# Implementation of Audio Video calling while using Agora Sdk in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

I'm using Agora SDK to implement Audio and video calling in React Native. I'm using the latest version of Agora SDK 4.3.2. I'm using official documentation of Agora during the implementation of Calling.

[This](https://docs.agora.io/en/voice-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=react-native) is the documentation link that I'm following for the implementation of Audio Calling. But the code doesn't seem to work and nothing happens on the screen. Do you know what is the real issue?

Tried official documentation of Agora
Tried Different YouTube videos
But no solution works for me.
Expect to help me in the integration of Audio and Video calling during the implementation

Comment: You can try "react-native-agora": "3.7.1" version.

Comment: Brother this gives version and dependencies issue

Comment: You say 'nothing happens on the screen.' Any logs?

Comment: you can share your codebase so that we can over view it and give a solution. Without seeing the solution, its difficult to give a solution.